# Docusign authentication timeout errors

Tags: selenium, docusignapi

We use Selenium which brings up a fresh (i.e., clear cache) Chrome browser

(Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)) but this happens also manually and with IE. And it is intermittent (maybe 80% of the time)

When signing in to sign a document, about 10% or 20% of the time everything works fine, but the rest of the time it just times out (spinning circle) or I get the error below:

*dsPrepare is not defined.*

We are inside a VPN. Not sure whether that matters or not?

Anyone know what is happening, or what this error means?

I did enter a question in the community too.

We are using Java (1.8) with Eclipse and Selenium

Comment: what url are you trying to load?

Comment: https://account-d.docusign.com/

Comment: can you repro this manually?

Comment: yeah, like 80% of the time.   Others do too with different logins

Comment: You think Docusign would be more attentive to its paying customers

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue even once, I would need more information. I also feel like you may need to contact support instead of posting here for your issue.

Comment: your question said "We are using Java (1.8) with Eclipse and Selenium" so you are not doing that? you can repo 80% manually?

Comment: Yes, and I and two other people have contacted support a few times but no response.

Comment: please contact me via email and also if you have contacted support, please provide in your email the support case number. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit how do I find your email address?  I will also try on linked in.  I see we have a couple shared contacts already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214420/discussion-between-tony-and-inbar-gazit).